# The area between $y=x$ and $y=2$ and the y-axis is divided into two equal parts by the line $x=c$, find the value of $c$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**The problem:**

The area between $y=x$ and $y=2$ and the $y$-axis is divided into two equal parts by the line $x=c$, find the value of $c$.
(The area is in the first quadrant.)

**The answer key:**

$c = 2 - \sqrt2$

**What I have tried:**

Half the area should be 1 because the whole area is 2.

$\int_0^c (2 - x) dx  = 1 \iff \left(2x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)_0^c = 1 \iff 2c - \frac{c^2}{2} = 1 \iff 4c - c^2 = 2 \iff$

$\iff c^2 - 4c + 2 = 0 \iff (c-2)^2 - 2^2 = -2 \iff (c-2)^2 = -2 + 4 \iff$

$\iff (c-2)^2 = 2 \iff c-2 = {\sqrt 2} \iff c = {\sqrt 2} + 2 $

How do I get the same answer as the answer key? I've looked at similar problems and still get an answer that doesn't match the answer key. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try? It's hard to tell where you're going wrong if you haven't shown your work

Comment: I tried to take the integral of x with the upper bound c and and lower bound 0 and then set that equal to 1, because I know the whole area will be 2, and then solve for c.

Comment: You are overthinking this a bit. The area of a triangle is $\frac{1}{2}bh$, right? So it's possible to use coordinate geometry.

Comment: @Nora your integral computes an area below the line $y=x$, but you should be looking above that line. Did you draw a picture of the given triangle?

Comment: The problem is asking for me to use definite integrals to solve this problem. I have drawn a picture, do I send a picture of it?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Just by trying to imagine the described setup, and using triangles I also get $c=\sqrt{2}$, so either the key is wrong or you've misread the exercise and typed your understanding here.

Comment: I've tried to translate it to the best of my ability from Swedish to English, but there could possibly have been something lost in translation. If I may ask, how was it you got that answer using integrals? I'm realizing that I can't just take the integral of "y = x", but instead have to take the integral of "2 - x" as I think the user "Karl" was getting at. Where do I continue from there? Because if I do that, integrate "2-x" and put the upper bound as "c" and the lower bound as "0", and set all of that equal to 1, I no longer get c = $sqrt(2)$.

Comment: Nora, it sounds like you're on the right track! Do you get the same answer as the answer key with your new integral? If you're still stuck, it'd help if you could edit the question and explain your progress.

Comment: I've updated the original post. It's the first time I'm using MathJax, so please excuse any possible mistakes. I'm still getting $c = {\sqrt 2}$. Do I just assume the answer key is wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm getting $c = {\sqrt 2} + 2$. Which still doesn't match the answer key.

Comment: But that's not inside the triangle you have to divide, so clearly wrong. You should show your workings, maybe then someone can figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I realize that I don't have the correct answer as it doesn't match the answer key. I have updated the original post with how I've gone about it using integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the effort in practicing MathJax! It's annoying at first but it definitely pays off over time. It's very nice to be able to type easy-to-read math formulas.

Your whole calculation is correct until this step: $$(c-2)^2 = 2 \iff c-2 = {\sqrt 2}$$
Instead, you should write
$$(c-2)^2 = 2 \iff c-2 = \pm{\sqrt 2}$$
This will lead to 2 solutions: $c = 2 \pm \sqrt{2}$. To see which one is correct, you can look back at your actual geometric situation to see that the correct $c$ must satisfy $0 \le c \le 2$ since otherwise the line $x=c$ won't touch your shape at all. Therefore the answer is $\boxed{c = 2 - \sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)